# Renaming the iframe src attribute to facilitate lazy loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm not great with javascript. I need some code to rename all iframe `src` attribute names to `data-src`, for a lazyload plugin to work. I couldn't find out how to rename the attribute names, but with some trial and error I managed something similar and it is working OK:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {   

     $( 'iframe' ).each(function() {

        //store each iframe scr attribute value in a variable
        var attr_value = $(this).attr("src");

        //Add a data-src attribute with the src attribute value
        $(this).attr('data-src', attr_value);

        // remove the old src attribute
        $(this).removeAttr('src');
    });
});
```

Does this look OK? or is there a better way to achieve this. Any help appreciated?

Comment: This code runs inside `$(document).ready(…)` — doesn't that mean that the iframes have already been loaded?

Comment: It doesn't seem to, I think it is different with iframes. My document is ready before the documents inside the iframes are ready. Isn't $( window ).load(function() {}) https://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/ the one for when everything has fully loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `$(this)` three times is a bit wasteful.  You can improve that by taking advantage of [`$.attr(attributeName, function)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) and by using chaining.

```js
$(function() {   
     $('iframe').attr('data-src', function() { return $(this).attr('src'); })
                .removeAttr('src');
});

// For demonstration...
$(function() {   
     $('#printout').text($('iframe').attr('data-src'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  data-src=<span id="printout"></span>
  <iframe width="10" height="10" src="http://codereview.stackexchange.com/"></iframe>
</body>
```